# Windows 8 Start Screen ribbon mysteriously replaced by context menu, how to reverse?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen, ribbon

When I first set up Windows 8 (core edition) on my desktop PC, it showed the following behavior when I right-clicked a start screen tile:

[image: start screen with ribbon]

It was possible to right-click multiple tiles and use the ribbon to act on all of them.

After a few hours, without my reconfiguring anything obviously related to the start screen, it changed so that right-clicking brings up a context menu instead:

[image: start screen with context menu]

Now if I want to act on multiple tiles, I have to ctrl-click them and then right-click to select an action.

What caused this change? How can I get the ribbon back?

Comment: Microsoft changed the behavior several weeks ago when Windows 8.1 Update 1 was released. The old behavior happens with installations with touch based devices. If you don't have a touch display there isn't a way to get the ribbon back. There also isn't a "home edition" its normally called "Core" instead of "Professional" or "Professional w/WMC"

Comment: It's on a desktop, not a touch device. Sounds like I must have gotten a stealthy update shortly after the install. Thanks for all the information. I'll update my question with the proper nomenclature, and if you want to post this as an answer I can accept it.